Работа с инвентарём в C#
Создал инвентарь. Два скрипта под него. Сделал UI инвентаря, то есть слоты. К объекту Inventory прикреплён код Inventory. Ну классический инвентарь
Так же сделал вещь, к ней прикрепил код Item
Но никак не могу сделать так, что если бы инвентарь был полным (все два слота заняты), то брать больше нельзя. По разному писал и делал, готов удариться об стенку уже.
Игрок берет первую вещь - всё ок, но на вторую (для этого выводится лог) пишет "Инвентарь полный". Что при второй пустой ячейке - бред. для удобства нейронкой ввёл документацию
Даю два класса, Первый Inventory
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool[] isFull;
    public GameObject[] slots;

    public bool AddItem(Item item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!isFull[i])
            {
                isFull[i] = true;
                GameObject itemGO = Instantiate(item.itemPrefab, slots[i].transform);

                // Настройка RectTransform для центрирования иконки
                RectTransform rectTransform = itemGO.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
                if (rectTransform == null)
                {
                    rectTransform = itemGO.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
                }

                // Центрирование
                rectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
                rectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
                rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;

                // Установка размера иконки
                rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(50, 50); // Измените размер по необходимости

                // Убедимся, что масштаб равен 1
                rectTransform.localScale = Vector3.one;

                // Если у префаба есть Image компонент, убедимся, что он заполняет родительский объект
                Image image = itemGO.GetComponent<Image>();
                if (image != null)
                {
                    image.preserveAspect = true;
                }

                return true; // Предмет успешно добавлен
            }
        }
        return false; // Все слоты заполнены, предмет не добавлен
    }

    public bool IsInventoryFull()
    {
        foreach (bool slotFull in isFull)
        {
            if (!slotFull)
            {
                return false; // Найден пустой слот
            }
        }
        return true; // Все слоты заполнены
    }
}

Второй Item:
using UnityEngine;

public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string itemName;
    public float dropChance = 0.5f;
    public int damageBonus = 5;
    public GameObject itemPrefab;
    public GameObject hintPrefab; // Префаб подсказки E
    public float displayDistance = 2f;
    public float itemHeight = 1f;

    private GameObject itemInstance;
    private GameObject hintInstance; // Экземпляр подсказки E
    private Transform playerTransform;
    private Camera mainCamera;

    private void Start()
    {
        playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        itemInstance = Instantiate(itemPrefab, CalculateItemPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
        itemInstance.SetActive(false);

        // Создаем экземпляр подсказки E
        hintInstance = Instantiate(hintPrefab, CalculateHintPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
        hintInstance.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float distanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerTransform.position);
        if (distanceToPlayer <= displayDistance)
        {
            ShowItem();
            ShowHint();
            CheckPickup();
        }
        else
        {
            HideItem();
            HideHint();
        }
        if (itemInstance != null && itemInstance.activeSelf)
        {
            UpdateItemPosition();
        }
        if (hintInstance != null && hintInstance.activeSelf)
        {
            UpdateHintPosition();
        }
    }

    private void ShowItem()
    {
        if (itemInstance != null && !itemInstance.activeSelf)
        {
            itemInstance.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void HideItem()
    {
        if (itemInstance != null && itemInstance.activeSelf)
        {
            itemInstance.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void ShowHint()
    {
        if (hintInstance != null && !hintInstance.activeSelf)
        {
            hintInstance.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void HideHint()
    {
        if (hintInstance != null && hintInstance.activeSelf)
        {
            hintInstance.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateItemPosition()
    {
        return transform.position + Vector3.up * itemHeight;
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateHintPosition()
    {
        return transform.position + Vector3.up * (itemHeight + 0.5f); // Подсказка немного выше предмета
    }

    private void UpdateItemPosition()
    {
        itemInstance.transform.position = CalculateItemPosition();
    }

    private void UpdateHintPosition()
    {
        hintInstance.transform.position = CalculateHintPosition();
        hintInstance.transform.LookAt(hintInstance.transform.position + mainCamera.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward,
            mainCamera.transform.rotation * Vector3.up);
    }

    private void CheckPickup()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            PlayerController player = playerTransform.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
            if (player != null)
            {
                Inventory inventory = player.GetComponent<Inventory>();
                if (inventory != null)
                {
                    if (!inventory.IsInventoryFull())
                    {
                        if (inventory.AddItem(this))
                        {
                            DestroyItemAndInstance();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Инвентарь полон! Нельзя подобрать предмет.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Компонент Inventory не найден на игроке!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void DestroyItemAndInstance()
    {
        if (itemInstance != null)
        {
            Destroy(itemInstance);
        }
        if (hintInstance != null)
        {
            Destroy(hintInstance);
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (itemInstance != null)
        {
            Destroy(itemInstance);
        }
        if (hintInstance != null)
        {
            Destroy(hintInstance);
        }
    }
}


А где у вас массивы isFull и slots инициализируются в Inventory? Сейчас это просто ссылки. А на что? Что там внутри, и откуда оно берётся? В приведённом коде проблем не видно. Вангую, что проблема в инициализации массива.

Переправил, как свободен буду вечером, исправлю код полностью.
Я так понял, что Вы private bool[] isFull;     private GameObject[] slots;
И затем
 private void Awake()
    {
        InitializeInventory();
    }

    private void InitializeInventory()
    {
        isFull = new bool[slotCount];
        slots = new GameObject[slotCount];
``` ...

Хм, вроде выглядит нормально. Ну попробуйте больше отладочных сообщений выводить, может что-то понятнее станет. А slotCount проверяли, он у вас точно не 1? )

slotCount в инспекторе установлен на 2. Я тоже думаю, что всё хорошо, но не могу разобраться. Crazy сказал, что проблема в инициализации. Я займусь этим и сниму вопрос. Даже если не получится

Может сразу два раза первое добавление срабатывает вместо одного? Тут только отладочным выводом всё фиксировать. Ну или в отладчике смотреть.

Вопрос был решён путем обновления класса подбора вещи.
В инвентарь внес новый метод HasFreeSlot(), а в самой вещи изменился немного метод проверки подбора.
